# Data page internal pull information

Tags: postgresql

Iam new here for postgresql..I want to know exactly inside how the pages is looks in postgresql-

have gone through some of articles like 8KB page but internally to understand quite difficulty but as a newer can some one provide how the page looks like and if anything can simulation exists let Me know I can use it for reference.

I have gone through the many links but its very difficult to understand as an new beginner if someone can tel easy way that helps for Me.

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-page-layout.html) is quite detailed on that.

If you need to know more, read the header file [`src/include/storage/bufpage.h`](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/include/storage/bufpage.h).